# One button respond to two textView

Tags: java, android, onclick

My app need to generate a random number and set it to a `TextView` and at the same time, set time from countdown timer on `TextView`  by click one button. However, I can't find solution on how to make it work.

```
public class GenerateToken extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView show;
CountDownT timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_generate_token);

    show =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    show.setText("60");
}

 public void generate (View v)
 {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(1999999999 - 1000000000)+1000000000;
    TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String myString = String.valueOf(number);
    myText.setText(myString);
        timer.start();
    }

}
public class CountDownT extends CountDownTimer{

    public CountDownT (long InMillisSeconds, long TimeGap){
        super(InMillisSeconds,TimeGap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l){
        show.setText((l/1000) +"");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(){
        show.setText("Request New Token..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is almost okay but I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong. What is the current behaviour? How does that differ from your expected behaviour? Also if you could edit your post to fix that code formatting that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy. Just set `setOnClickListener()` on your `Button` and change those `TextView`. Like -

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   textView1.setText("Text changed on TextView 1");
                   textView2.setText("Text changed on TextView2");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am guessing u add `onClick="generate"` in your button xml.

```
public class GenerateToken extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView show;
TextView myText;
CountDownT timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_generate_token);
    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    show =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    show.setText("60");
 }

 public void generate (View v)
 {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(1999999999 - 1000000000)+1000000000;
    String myString = String.valueOf(number);
    myText.setText(myString);

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          show.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000+"");
       }

       public void onFinish() {
          //{code to do after the timer finishes}
       }

    }.start();

 }
}
```

Here 30000 is milliseconds to count and 1000 is interval. So here it countdown for 30secs. Change the time according to ur need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It solve my issues. I really appreciate it.